# check if string contains sub string from the same column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have the following dataframe:

```
> df1
  col1  
0 donald     
1 mike
2 donald trump
3 trump
4 mike pence
5 pence
6 jarred
```

i want to check for the strings that contain sub string from this column and create a new column that holds the bigger strings if the condition is full filled

something like this:

```
> df1
  col1           col2
0 donald        donald trump
1 mike          mike pence
2 donald trump  donald trump
3 trump         donald trump
4 mike pence    mike pence
5 pence         mike pence
6 jarred        jarred
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
df['Col2'] = df['Col1'].apply(lambda x: max([i for i in df['Col1'] if x in i], key=len))
```

Comment: And dont forget add list comprehension alternative :) +1

Comment: @jezrael I can only think of `filter` at the moment.